# Google drive api v3 response null

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I want to try upload file google drive and my code is here:

```
 public static File UploadFile(DriveService service, string fileName, string filePath, string description, string parent)
{
  var fileMetadata = new File
  {
    Name = fileName,
    MimeType = GetMimeType(fileName),
    Description = description,
    OriginalFilename = fileName,
  };

  FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
  using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
  {
      request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, GetMimeType(fileName));
      request.Fields = "id";
      request.Alt=FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload.AltEnum.Json;
      request.Upload();
  }
  var file = request.ResponseBody;
  Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);


  return null;

}
```

But Response body is always null and i cant upload. By the way i saw error in this picture:

google-api-dotnet-client 1.16.0.0 gzip the format of the invalid value

Anyone idea how to solve this problem and upload files google drive.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the C#, but you can try this tutorial on how to upload files in Google Drive using C#. This [tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/) will explain everything to you like authentication, files, update, upload, download, file permission and etc. This tutorial also includes sample project that you can follow. For more information, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) of Google on how to upload files.

Comment: Thanks but im not trouble with authentication and sample that you gave me using google api v2 .  i'm trying goog api v3.

Answer (score 2):

It appears V3 has replaced InsertMediaUpload for CreateMediaUpload and when using a service account at least the ResponseBody will always be returned as NULL.

This makes it difficult to determine the ID of the file and later find it to modify permissions or do anything else.