# Null response creating file using Google Drive .NET API

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file onto my Drive using Google Drive .NET API v3. My code is below

```
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                       DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                       DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                       DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,
                       DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,
                       DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts };
    static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("C:/Users/admin1/Documents/visual studio 2017/Projects/TryGoogleDrive/TryGoogleDrive/client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Debug.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
            .Files;
        Debug.WriteLine("Files:");
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No files found.");
        }

        var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
        {
            Name = "report.csv",
            MimeType = "text/csv",
        };
        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("C:/debugging/report.csv",
                                FileMode.Open))
        {
            request = service.Files.Create(
                fileMetadata, stream, "text/csv");
            request.Fields = "id";
            request.Upload();
        }
        var response = request.ResponseBody;
        Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + response.Id);

        return View();        
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that response is always null. I looked into it a bit further and found that the request returned a 403 resultCode. I also took a look at some other questions on SO [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468798/google-drive-api-v3-response-null) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021931/google-drive-api-v2-insertmediaupload-null-response-received?rq=1) but neither were of any help.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the first part of the code is working correctly - it lists all the files in my Drive. Only the second part is not working (the upload file part)

Answer (score 1):

```
    string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
```

- Change the Drive scope then delete the file token.json
- in vs2017 you can see token.json file in token.json folder when client_secret.json file present.

[image: click to see token.json]

Answer (score 0):

Try to visit [this post](https://forums.asp.net/t/2096352.aspx?Upload%20Files%20to%20Google%20Drive%20by%20ASP%20Net%20C%20) from ASP.NET forum.

The same idea as what you want to do in your app, since you are dealing with uploading a file in Google Drive using .net.

> You may try to call rest api directly to achieve your requirement :

[The quickstart from .net](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet) will help you to make requests from/to the Drive API.

[Upload Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#multipart):

> The Drive API allows you to upload file data when [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) or
>   [updating](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) a [File](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/) resource.
>
> You can send upload requests in any of the following ways:
>
> - Simple upload: `uploadType=media`. For quick transfer of a small file (5 MB or less). To perform a simple upload, refer to [Performing
>     a Simple Upload.](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/simple-upload)
> - Multipart upload: `uploadType=multipart`. For quick transfer of a small file (5 MB or less) and metadata describing the file, all in a
>     single request. To perform a multipart upload, refer to [Performing a
>     Multipart Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/multipart-upload).
> - Resumable upload: `uploadType=resumable`. For more reliable transfer, especially important with large files. Resumable uploads are
>     a good choice for most applications, since they also work for small
>     files at the cost of one additional HTTP request per upload. To
>     perform a resumable upload, refer to [Performing a Resumable
>     Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload).

You may try this code from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#basic_uploads) on uploading sample file.

```
var fileMetadata = new File()
{
    Name = "photo.jpg"
};
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("files/photo.jpg",
                        System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    request = driveService.Files.Create(
        fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
    request.Fields = "id";
    request.Upload();
}
var file = request.ResponseBody;
Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

You may check the errors you may encounter in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what `request.Upload()` returns. For me when I was having this issue it returned:

> Insufficient Permission Errors [Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ]

I changed my scope from `DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly` to `DriveService.Scope.Drive` and I was in business.

Answer (score 0):

Change `static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };` to `static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };`.

After changes, take a look into `token.json` file and check does it change its scope from `DriveReadonly` to `Drive`.

If you are seeing `DriveReadonly` then delete the `token.json` file and run the application again.