# c# google drive upload file

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Hi I want to upload file google drive but every time ,
I have this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I do every think this video series [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhQPwrrJ9kI).I accepted google drive upload request.
I tried zip , jpg, txt upload but same error. 
And I try Google.Apis.Drive.v2 but same error.
 What can I do? Please help sorry my English :(

```
private static string ApplicationName = "MysqlYedekleme";
    private static string FolderId = "1g_PTi5lQBCbZBax_3foZPdiECOC7cSaU";
    private static string filename = "test.rar";
    private static string filePath = @"E:\yedekdeneme\test.rar";
    private static string contentType = "application/zip";
    //drve
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserCredential credential = GetUserCredential();
        DriveService service = GetDriveService(credential);
        uploadFileDrive(service, filename, filePath, contentType);
    }

    private static UserCredential GetUserCredential()
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string creadPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            creadPath = Path.Combine(creadPath, "driveApiCredentials", "drive-credentials.json");
            return GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(

                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "User",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(creadPath, true)).Result;

        }
    }

    private static DriveService GetDriveService(UserCredential credential)
    {
        return new DriveService
            (new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

    }
    private static string uploadFileDrive(DriveService service, string filename, string filePath, string contentType)
    {

        try
        {
           var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        fileMetadata.Name = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        fileMetadata.MimeType = "application/zip";
                  fileMetadata.Parents = new List<string> { FolderId };

        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
        using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, contentType);
            request.Fields = "id";
            request.Upload();
        }
        var file = request.ResponseBody;
        return file.Id;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("geldi:"+exc.Message);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Hi I try every think I  download this project https://github.com/NicolaMagnabosco/GoogleDrive_Uploader_NET
and load my client secret but same error

Comment: If you can tell me which line is throwing the NullReferenceException, I can suggest what might be null.

Comment: uploadedFileDrive (); if I write this  after request.upload();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("errorr:"+request.ResponseBody);//this line

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662041/null-response-creating-file-using-google-drive-net-api)

Comment: Nothing change @John

Comment: Can you please post your stacktrace?

Comment: Have you considered following the official examples?  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads